# Adding data to a PowerShell array / Add-Member

Tags: powershell, active-directory, active-directory-group

I am trying to write a PowerShell script that will compile together a list of groups in Active Directory along with the members of each group.  My ultimate goal is to export this out to a CSV files, so I want the final PowerShell multi-dimensional array to have the following format:

```
GroupName           GroupMember
Domain Admins       Henry Doe
Domain Admins       Melody Doe
Domain Names        Doe Ray Me
Domain Users        John Doe
Domain Users        Jane Doe
(etc…)
```

I am using the following code to try and do this:

```
[array]$arrGroupMemberList = New-Object PSObject
Add-Member -InputObject $arrGroupMemberList -membertype NoteProperty -Name 'GroupName' -Value ""
Add-Member -InputObject $arrGroupMemberList -membertype NoteProperty -Name 'GroupMember' -Value ""
[array]$arrGroupMemberList = @()

[array]$arrGroupNameObjects = Get-ADGroup -Filter * | Where-Object {$_.Name -Like "Domain*"}

If ($arrGroupNameObjects.Count -ge 1)
    {
    ## Cycle thru each group name and get the members
    $arrGroupNameObjects | ForEach-Object {
        [string]$strTempGroupName = $_.Name
        $arrGroupMemberObjects = Get-ADGroupMember $strTempGroupName -Recursive
        If ($arrGroupMemberObjects.Count -ge 1)
            {
            ## Cycle thru the group members and compile into the final array
            $arrGroupMemberObjects | ForEach-Object {
                $arrGroupMemberList += $strTempGroupName, $_.Name
            }
            }
    }
    }
```

My problem is, I keep ending up with the following as my array:

```
Domain Admins
Henry Doe
Domain Admins
Melody Doe
Domain Names
Doe Ray Me
Domain Users
John Doe
Domain Users
Jane Doe
```

I've tried a few different ways and I've searched but haven’t found the answer anywhere.  I’m sure that it is something simple, but what am I doing wrong?  Can I create a multi-dimensional array with the necessary data like I am trying to do?  If I use the following instead:

```
            ## Cycle thru the group members and compile into the final array
            $arrGroupMemberObjects | ForEach-Object {
                $arrGroupMemberList[$intIndex].GroupName = $strTempGroupName
                $arrGroupMemberList[$intIndex].GroupMember = $_.Name
                $intIndex++
```

I end up with errors like:

```
Property 'GroupMember' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
Property 'GroupName' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
```

Thanks

****UPDATE****

I may have found out where my problem is, it may be when I am adding the array members.  At the end of my PowerShell script, I am adding the following line of code:

```
$arrGroupMemberList | Get-Member
```

There are no properties, my elements are not there, even though I added them with Add-Member cmdlet earlier in the script.  Am I using the Add-Member cmdlet properly?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to use the following line to add rows to your table (two dimensional array).

$arrGroupMemberList += ,($strTempGroupName, $_.Name)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2007/01/23/array-literals-in-powershell.aspx

Comment: Thanks but tried that, still didn't work for me.  I found out some new information and will update my question

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what I was doing wrong - I was using **Add-Member** incorrectly.  I was trying to use **Add-Member** to add members to a collection, and it doesn't seem to work that way.  Something that simple but I really didn't see it discussed anywhere.  So I found some examples and did the trial-and-error thing and got it to work.  So I wanted to post an update back here in case anyone else has the same issue.  The following code works just like I want it to (and will create an array with a list of groups from Active Directory along with the group members in each group):

```
[array]$arrGroupNameObjects = Get-ADGroup -Filter * | Where-Object {$_.Name -Like "Domain*"}

If ($arrGroupNameObjects.Count -ge 1)
    {
    ## Cycle thru each group name and get the members
    $arrGroupNameObjects | ForEach-Object {
        [string]$strTempGroupName = $_.Name
        $arrGroupMemberObjects = Get-ADGroupMember $strTempGroupName -Recursive
        If ($arrGroupMemberObjects.Count -ge 1)
            {
            ## Cycle thru the group members and compile into the final array
            $arrGroupMemberObjects | ForEach-Object {
                $objGroupMember = New-Object PSObject
                Add-Member -InputObject $objGroupMember -membertype NoteProperty -Name 'GroupName' -Value $strTempGroupName
                Add-Member -InputObject $objGroupMember -membertype NoteProperty -Name 'GroupMemberName' -Value $_.Name
                [array]$arrGroupMemberList += $objGroupMember
            }
            }
    }
    }
```